# Extract certain text from long string in mysql field and update to different field

Tags: mysql, extract, text-extraction

What i want to do is extract the price from a long string of info in a mysql field and then update a different field with that price.

The long string field looks like this (2 examples);

a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:6:{s:4:"uenc";s:92:"aHR0cDovL3d3dy5yYXR0YW5kaXJlY3QuY28udWsvb3hmb3JkLWRpbmluZy1zZXQtdGVzdC00Lmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,";s:7:"product";s:4:"4938";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:17:"bundle_option_qty";a:1:{i:1457;s:1:"1";}s:13:"bundle_option";a:2:{i:1457;s:4:"9588";i:1455;s:4:"9492";}s:3:"qty";i:1;}s:27:"bundle_selection_attributes";s:97:"a:4:{s:5:"price";d:**600**;s:3:"qty";d:1;s:12:"option_label";s:5:"Bench";s:9:"option_id";s:4:"1455";}";}

a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:6:{s:4:"uenc";s:92:"aHR0cDovL3d3dy5yYXR0YW5kaXJlY3QuY28udWsvb3hmb3JkLWRpbmluZy1zZXQtdGVzdC00Lmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,";s:7:"product";s:4:"4938";s:15:"related_product";s:0:"";s:17:"bundle_option_qty";a:1:{i:1457;s:1:"1";}s:13:"bundle_option";a:2:{i:1457;s:4:"9588";i:1455;s:4:"9492";}s:3:"qty";i:1;}s:27:"bundle_selection_attributes";s:98:"a:4:{s:5:"price";d:**1300**;s:3:"qty";d:1;s:12:"option_label";s:5:"Chair";s:9:"option_id";s:4:"1457";}";}

Ideally i would just search for the s:5:"price";d: section as info before and after can change.

Any ideas?

Many thanks for looking

David

Comment: Forgot to mention that the bit i want to extract are bolded

Comment: I do not see an easy way to do this with sql if at all. If you know python, I would use that.  Otherwise, I would look at using a stored procedure.